# Spring MVC 5 Rest API convert XML to Bean using JAXB

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson-dataformat-xml

We are migrating Jersey Endpoints to Spring MVC Rest endpoints. These endpoints consumes and produces XML. But Spring MVC is unable to convert the XML input bean because XML tag and Bean's property name is different. I have to take request as String and Convert it using JAXB explicitly. Is there any better way to do that?

**Web Configuration**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
        public static final String JAXB_PACKAGE = "com.comp.platform.dataholder";
    
        @Autowired
        private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder;
    
        @Override
        public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    
            converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            converters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
            converters.add(createXmlHttpMessageConverter());
    
            converters.add(createMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter(builder));
            // converters.add(createMappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(xmlMapper));
    
            Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
            jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
            converters.add(jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter);
    
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder customJson() {
            return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().indentOutput(true).serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                    .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE).failOnUnknownProperties(false);
        }
    
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public ObjectMapper createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    
            ObjectMapper mapper = builder.build();
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
            return mapper;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
            Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
            marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(NonFinancialDataHolder.class, JaxbDataHolder.class, ViestimateDataHolder.class,CTRequest.class,com.app.rest.PolicyDetailRequest.class,com.app.rest.TransactionSubmitRequest.class,com.app.rest.AgentSuppressInfoRequest.class);
    
            return marshaller;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return
         */
        @Bean
        public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter createMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter(
                Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            converter.setObjectMapper(builder.build());
            return converter;
        }
        
        @Autowired
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller;
    
        private HttpMessageConverter<Object> createXmlHttpMessageConverter() {
            Assert.notNull(jaxb2Marshaller, "Jaxb Marshaller dependency required");
            MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(jaxb2Marshaller);
            xmlConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    
            return xmlConverter;
        }
    
        public JAXBContext getMarshaller() throws JAXBException {
            return JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXB_PACKAGE);
        }
    
    }
```

**Bean**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "_UserId",
        "_Password",
        "_RequestDateTime",
        "_Policy"
})
    @XmlRootElement(name = "PolicyDetailRequest")
    public class PolicyDetailRequest
    {
        @XmlElement(name = "UserId")
        protected String _UserId;
        @XmlElement(name = "Password")
        protected String _Password;
        @XmlElement(name = "RequestDateTime")
        protected String _RequestDateTime;
        @XmlElement(name = "Policy")
        protected String _Policy;
    }
```

**Rest Endpoint**

```
@Slf4j 
@RestController    
@RequestMapping("/api")  
public class api
{
    @Autowired
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller;

    @PostMapping(value="/PolicyResponse",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public PolicyDetailResponse getPolicyResponse(@RequestBody String data)
    {
        PolicyDetailRequest request = (PolicyDetailRequest) jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(data)));
        PolicyDetailResponse response = new PolicyDetailResponse();
        InternetRSHandler handler = new InternetRSHandler();
    
        response= handler.getPolicyRSResponse(request);
    
        return response;
    
    }
}
```

**Input Request**

```
<PolicyDetailRequest>
    <UserId>1234567890</UserId> 
    <Password>password</Password> 
    <RequestDateTime>20200420-15:07:23</RequestDateTime>
    <Policy>A76ABCD12</Policy>
</PolicyDetailRequest>
```

Comment: I would say that you are trying too-hard to (re)configure Spring MVC. Ditch the config and only leave `@EnableWebMvc` and `@Configuration`. When JAXB is present the `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` will be added automatically and should do its job.

Comment: Thanks. Since I have multiple Dispatcher servlet I had to add the configuration to the corresponding XML and removed it from context loader